# Laravel 4 Sessions error - Duplicate entry '4294967295' for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the database session driver in Laravel Four. MySQL DB.

Things were working fine, then I got this error. Trying on different computers all returns the same error.

I truncated the sessions table and reset the auto_increment value. This resolved it for a while, then it happened again.

Looking at the records in the sessions table, the ids would sometimes increment by one, but other times jump by varying amounts, but none near the max value for `int(11)`. Then what appears to be randomly, a session is stored with the max value then everything stops.

Has anyone else seen this kind of error with Laravel Four? Any ideas on whats causing it?

The app is part API and part CMS. Switching to the native sessions driver has resolved the problem so far. But I would like to be able to use the DB driver if I can get it to work.

Comment: For what it's worth, that's FFFFFFFF or -1, depending on how you look at it.

Comment: just a suggestion, but perhaps you could use GUIDs for your Session database instead of autoincrement.

Answer (score 0):

**step 1:**   `select max(your primary_key_field) from your_table_name;` 
**step 2:**   `ALTER TABLE your_table_name AUTO_INCREMENT = value_u_got_from_step1 + 1;`
you can put any value instead of 1 in`step2`...
I think this may work...

Answer (score 0):

Manually reset the auto_increment. Deleting all table rows is not enough.

ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1